# How can I avoid "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue" only using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

some time ago I had developed an algorithm that enters the "csgostash.com" page to obtain different information from it. It turns out that a few days ago I came across that when the code gets the html of the page, it returns "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue":

I know of the existence of Selenium to be able to activate Javascript and cookies, but is there any way that I can make my code get the correct html from the page only using BeautifulSoup? It is also important to mention that yesterday I ran the code again and it worked correctly but today the page returned "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue" again.

I tried using this code to get the correct html:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://csgostash.com/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

But this is what I get instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Just a moment...</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots"/>
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body class="no-js">
<div class="main-wrapper" role="main">
<div class="main-content">
<noscript>
<div id="challenge-error-title">
<div class="h2">
<span class="icon-wrapper">
<div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>
</span>
<span id="challenge-error-text">
                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
                    </span>
</div>
</div>
</noscript>
<div id="trk_jschal_js" style="display:none;background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=7c19a3114e16ab35')"></div>
<form action="/?__cf_chl_f_tk=ObSCNTBjXQ1uRVTTXTRWnK8EtvJQDPXuH3ujSLKZf8g-1683128788-0-gaNycGzNCmU" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="challenge-form" method="POST">
<input name="md" type="hidden" value="0NZizUSp7FsBu6utGwTdOUpUzi1tuB730H2s7jI4DYQ-1683128788-0-AWTcqAHAaoLlsjptIqz9QZtXaqK-g2lRbxFcOacCvfcc_z2PO91XfhrCyS_pWN3VfUBF7wj25BHZLEJ1MlJE8t-ID9imoLKthOcInptAr0jQ6OtnM9qBBRqmGngAcIfo4fJVFR3vk1to-mE9dD3VSAV_Ux3IVZlprtPQsWXaSzEc7aKYoiTMzbxpP4ICNfuWPu5_Q49d26Oz4D2nVzJZZJj706duo9kK0oWKosGIpAWYJ3Kpe4278eCjh4CAEUYIH3M1E-F2fAh3KOLGc-GJXNtOZ7Yqic-t8vHw2C1UIqedkZWyN-DHlgAfY7ad4OSTr4fsGjFlK8BbGQ-rgzQKsdRCCXxK9OnfRou8D9WFSJ5uEr-Nvtm7SsQ_9H47nUKXxhi6kSCCL6_v1T3-ywXg498Zljolwe9UOxLesZ923HHMYViCDPXavh1xM2j29gU3UqTeGh6FbvXx1EJ0T8wbrxeMmjb8mOQ3-N5yF3gESt7EkYVZaqTS9pKB7blX_OK13tC9pKhEQtzCmu2L8uCh5hmoaZQiJPq8BK4gruWg-rmGvJCGObWxTLWp5C6p0mQfT3DQUs8nr6PwaTMpnKceVQ8_AFcozd67dg3TaqPfDw4JrK-7jvnB8aCEPAyaKzNsmV4k1GNtCLdjejVSmjLtkQDCXbb53A0ac5nH-tcb7EFMx4J_ByfGmjK9LB3azXBQBKU9lFaCkR7uEvul4Bqkv_aA6l8kx9_vcfjbcjs7Appr6jeutpTRWDc1BUf8MCofipmctCWq_TNUBEVyBNHVlBwyBtUDQ_S3oR7zoeA0ni4I1_PD2_XXGxQCTm1-PVWYcMhLVtHCdiVmvAVHYYHU9CLHPJ0V8jW9FPM8TqvRgRWL5BpceMZjkizzL1GohK-Yy_ZmGtR6kxfZqkHBVUCVsqqhxYMKviyDfIjoAacC1A0FV2iWI0eKLJXkCuPI2Z95EE0eUuuwv5QMIm0mbZ1k05h8z1Zxp5_Pl1s0M76Mpeh_IltGHEBKJSwbhJhGIJwutyFZ-2AP8SITh6T2KDVWvaUzJ9Fj33yUtolszsgmbhHjRc2zcbzxN3F8wbcqcjLtMCQTrVoCbGzBPVXJQ33zNzuOcV-iKv2TjvNWyLn6T-KO34zk28T1sh5cW_F0FGiZ5_DH_K2Ar1uVZ7dWAPCHqto4-xqAntd_nNYVN8GDwfJRsGRjcy6L8jsk0i57zfN5ukMs9r2ZAwRJnIui9R0NWEnokKQF3njVZ3Po3l6xL1zDMu73v7SvpQLO7-R1oA3lS20ce1MZ2xk_M_3YVxa9uYUpQzc5H4TT1IfBKpJQ6fBIMmB1EwvDUyfifPtPJzN9Q5hfgxRA_66wjMmOVYiyxJIoiqveh3-_NCIvKSETQ6FEbC4jLmU5PyqwJBvR1US3chLZhC1GOZEF-Q8gU3jXv4Y76wvZq94U7fcnkG5YWAzTY6LeXsYbdK9Kcr-i0_iAN1TEhj_flXHPaoEzhLATsuhl2qf9M5Umx4do5gDTiLfZoF4B-1xj1glox7XKb-Uyt12mnUnC2MEbgifIPLQZkrPMnm9thqhiIXM9twlnGCHKAa1ZnlloV8p34jAyUKh13ytrIe797KvFYqvglrZT9BGGQyCTrpGbwBoG1zATc42bc8jlX2gurj5oQs_3yI8YmmVMPx22tmu63smABnNgoqTTuoIFvYveWNhtKv1gC9GT68P-sCNeNXAOzeBkvC682S-dXQK2mfQeRS2z-LZ7bX4UH1jkZGhpSaP9qqZWXWwrLMwwEsb6w3KIjTuoRjVcnUTYwzbVWAkHfWDCI2-b-mP9XzfUAzQvQrRVwsQtEKTNoK7QzsxQFsfg3a7rPBSf0-ysBhU7MqPxYd94fqzdsjDFPekTVoLHtY6YL1m4MTfXCbytDmKztyrP1xAUTaBJPThwDuWsbByreLs3lRj8Ekpxeysm4XrTMCYlEpEUtIfOCYbmzYHUz--pOWSBfAlbEPUOJIXl2gv5CKVqsXWF3hRNQJqjMGtdY2FalkDORzEdmlkbU1eSKVQ17gHT9wdpp4lTvVPI4sYiTSq9hA56D8sIHT-iFT3OhGoJpu4I9VDyRdyP-f8YoXiEZmxxONTif06nKfqjYG7ahSOespzeGjPLCQ1r5a67koAZcqaotQgwiBtYDQ4YBRTFBwiJID-FOJcmoo5gPjQL5QlJOFw_feF1uGu63KH_r59uAEtskOcgX-607KTUiA_7EtQvSmaADGDBVWStj2Zri-gh9_xdIMVQq0Wn8H56NTkv02H_wlr9OvlY57EEzj2He5qKaIR16FAVFJjfqgGq56icZfSQPKhAFPj0MqP2V5pdMEgWVM5mPuc2SQdvf3WxQcXGbFlr_ULeEuQreRaS5i8QEGZbmylcYv4PG0Y6Kc1lCeo3F1XUTFNsdRvmNXQWPIaMri5BkM7ayTa1NS2Mtggvbcem26AAk6K5D4LlOtdPg4_6kzm_kXxq-sVXh0JxA7gb7jbGNLoLb1jdeKyuYUIooeu_h5S1Z42EqIZHxtA-w15wodU17jgJCkp7Mx-hq4MpzPot_x2nj_o6Xj6eST7yZvfKpxyTwLp_mvEcGxd5ys-N0xq0"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    (function(){
        window._cf_chl_opt={
            cvId: '2',
            cZone: 'csgostash.com',
            cType: 'managed',
            cNounce: '3894',
            cRay: '7c19a3114e16ab35',
            cHash: '24208680a9071cc',
            cUPMDTk: "\/?__cf_chl_tk=ObSCNTBjXQ1uRVTTXTRWnK8EtvJQDPXuH3ujSLKZf8g-1683128788-0-gaNycGzNCmU",
            cFPWv: 'g',
            cTTimeMs: '1000',
            cMTimeMs: '0',
            cTplV: 5,
            cTplB: 'cf',
            cK: "",
            cRq: {
                ru: 'aHR0cHM6Ly9jc2dvc3Rhc2guY29tLw==',
                ra: 'cHl0aG9uLXJlcXVlc3RzLzIuMjUuMQ==',
                rm: 'R0VU',
                d: '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',
                t: 'MTY4MzEyODc4OC42OTMwMDA=',
                m: 's2xe7eKZIFDmXxfF5UCDi+iJL3ELnk09HkXTGHn0qSk=',
                i1: 'xcqC3YXmgIfppbJrhxJ1GA==',
                i2: 'CXiClmMebTrg5lDfngZx+Q==',
                zh: '4tDrCUth59uGjNDbwkRUSDT9GVt/jpkGLb/CvaMy/rU=',
                uh: '5GU+jYv2xJ+bCaE/ARmi/DORbiS/v56CW7E0TH4XWQk=',
                hh: 'aaecX9/pdLWMoIFOKEr7lncUO+QJ96Bak184hcZ9dao=',
            }
        };
        var trkjs = document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute('src', '/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/js/transparent.gif?ray=7c19a3114e16ab35');
        trkjs.setAttribute('alt', '');
        trkjs.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo = document.createElement('script');
        cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/managed/v1?ray=7c19a3114e16ab35';
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;        
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, location.href.length - window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;
        if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;
            history.replaceState(null, null, "\/?__cf_chl_rt_tk=ObSCNTBjXQ1uRVTTXTRWnK8EtvJQDPXuH3ujSLKZf8g-1683128788-0-gaNycGzNCmU" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);
            cpo.onload = function() {
                history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
            };
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you can see, there's nothing else in the HTML for you to get. Everything is created dynamically using JavaScript.